# Copy some fields from one table to another in MySQL with or without data

Tags: mysql

i am searching for hours and not found a good answer of this ,can anybody help me out to do this in MySQL:

1. How to copy both the structure and data of Table-1 into Table-2,
    Table-1 and Table-2are given below:-
2. How to copy the structure of Table-1 into Table-2 without any data .

   ```
   [Table-1  Store_Information]
   Store_Name  Sales   Txn_Date
   Los Angeles 1500    Jan-05-1999
   San Diego   250     Jan-07-1999
   Los Angeles 300     Jan-08-1999
   Boston      700     Jan-08-1999

   [Table-2  Geography]
   Region_Name Store_Name
   East        Boston
   East        New York
   West        Los Angeles
   West        San Diego
   ```

I also tried some examples found on other threads like

```
SELECT column_name1,column_name2,..
INTO new_table
FROM table_name;
```

and

```
INSERT INTO table2
column1, column2..
SELECT column1, column2, ..
FROM table1;
```

Both queries i found from these links:-
http://blog.ubiq.co/copy-data-into-new-table-mysql/ 
http://blog.ubiq.co/insert-data-from-one-table-into-another-mysql/
But nothing seems to work.
First query does not work because MySQL does not support SELECT INTO.
Well insert statement will work when there will be a column in table2. So the main issue is how to copy some columns from one table to another table. Just structure, not data.

I am using MySQL. Database is same.Both tables is in same database. Both tables already exists in database.

Please help me to do this.

Comment: Instead of `SELECT INTO`, MySQL supports [`CREATE TABLE...SELECT...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html)

Answer (score 3):

To copy the structure without data you can use the `LIKE` option to `CREATE TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 LIKE table1;
```

You can then copy all the data with:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
```

If you want to copy some columns along with their data, you can do:

```
CREATE TABLE table2
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM table1
```

This will just copy the datatypes, it won't copy indexes and options like `auto_increment`.

To copy some columns without any data, you could use the above procedure, but a `WHERE` clause that selects no rows:

```
CREATE TABLE table2
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE 1 = 0
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar to answer and arrange my question content, i tried this and it works very fine. but i want to copy some of the fields of table1 to the table 2, not all the fields.

Comment: if you don't want to copy all the fields, then there's nothing automatic.

Comment: Is there a way to copy selected fields if the target table already exists in database.

Comment: You mean you want to add new columns to the target table? That has to be done with `ALTER TABLE`, and I don't think there's any way to tell that to copy from another table.